# mediaelement.js show download link

Tags: mediaelement.js

Currently i'm working on a html5 video with MediaElement.js. It works perfect in Chrome, but only showing a download link in Firefox.

here's the html:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <video width="680" height="255" id="vid-holder">
       <source src="media/JonesLangLaselle_1210_final.webm" type="video/webm"/>
       <source src="media/JonesLangLaselle_1210_final.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
       <source src="media/JonesLangLaselle_1210_final.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>
    </video>
</div>
```

is there any problem with the source hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer, hope it helps.

just add preload attribute in the video tag

added, to be:

```
<video width="680" height="255" id="vid-holder" preload="none">
```

Comment: Would you mind adding the fixed source? This way one might more likely upvote your answer. And you should also accept your own answer to show that this question has actually been answered!